# Deserialize response soap service in C #

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I am currently receiving this response from a svc soap service:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <soap:Fault>
            <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
            <faultstring>[0417] - El identificador de petición y de solicitud no coinciden.</faultstring>
            <faultactor>Seguridad Social</faultactor>
            <detail>
                <Atributos xmlns="http://intermediacion.redsara.es/scsp/esquemas/V3/soapfaultatributos">
                    <IdPeticion>HACSGTIC-2016111056-0036</IdPeticion>
                    <NumElementos>1</NumElementos>
                    <TimeStamp>2016-11-10T11:56:51.687+01.00</TimeStamp>
                    <Estado>
                        <CodigoEstado>0417</CodigoEstado>
                        <LiteralError>[0417] - El identificador de petición y de solicitud no coinciden.</LiteralError>
                        <TiempoEstimadoRespuesta />
                    </Estado>
                    <CodigoCertificado>Q2827002CINSS001</CodigoCertificado>
                </Atributos>
            </detail>
        </soap:Fault>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I need to deserialize the xml Attributes because I have an "Attributes" object with the properties corresponding to the xml, then I put the class Attributes of the reference of the service:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.6.1064.2")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="http://intermediacion.redsara.es/scsp/esquemas/V3/peticion")]
public partial class Atributos : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private string idPeticionField;

    private int numElementosField;

    private string timeStampField;

    private Estado estadoField;

    private CodigoCertificado codigoCertificadoField;

    /// <comentarios/>
    public string IdPeticion {
        get {
            return this.idPeticionField;
        }
        set {
            this.idPeticionField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("IdPeticion");
        }
    }

    /// <comentarios/>
    public int NumElementos {
        get {
            return this.numElementosField;
        }
        set {
            this.numElementosField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("NumElementos");
        }
    }

    /// <comentarios/>
    public string TimeStamp {
        get {
            return this.timeStampField;
        }
        set {
            this.timeStampField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("TimeStamp");
        }
    }

    /// <comentarios/>
    public Estado Estado {
        get {
            return this.estadoField;
        }
        set {
            this.estadoField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("Estado");
        }
    }

    /// <comentarios/>
    public CodigoCertificado CodigoCertificado {
        get {
            return this.codigoCertificadoField;
        }
        set {
            this.codigoCertificadoField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("CodigoCertificado");
        }
    }

    public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
        if ((propertyChanged != null)) {
            propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}


[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.6.1064.2")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="http://intermediacion.redsara.es/scsp/esquemas/V3/peticion")]
public partial class Estado : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private string codigoEstadoField;

    private string codigoEstadoSecundarioField;

    private string literalErrorField;

    private int tiempoEstimadoRespuestaField;

    private bool tiempoEstimadoRespuestaFieldSpecified;

    /// <comentarios/>
    public string CodigoEstado {
        get {
            return this.codigoEstadoField;
        }
        set {
            this.codigoEstadoField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("CodigoEstado");
        }
    }

    /// <comentarios/>
    public string CodigoEstadoSecundario {
        get {
            return this.codigoEstadoSecundarioField;
        }
        set {
            this.codigoEstadoSecundarioField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("CodigoEstadoSecundario");
        }
    }

    /// <comentarios/>
    public string LiteralError {
        get {
            return this.literalErrorField;
        }
        set {
            this.literalErrorField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("LiteralError");
        }
    }

    /// <comentarios/>
    public int TiempoEstimadoRespuesta {
        get {
            return this.tiempoEstimadoRespuestaField;
        }
        set {
            this.tiempoEstimadoRespuestaField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("TiempoEstimadoRespuesta");
        }
    }

    /// <comentarios/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool TiempoEstimadoRespuestaSpecified {
        get {
            return this.tiempoEstimadoRespuestaFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.tiempoEstimadoRespuestaFieldSpecified = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("TiempoEstimadoRespuestaSpecified");
        }
    }

    public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
        if ((propertyChanged != null)) {
            propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}

/// <comentarios/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.6.1064.2")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="http://intermediacion.redsara.es/scsp/esquemas/V3/peticion")]
public enum CodigoCertificado {

    /// <comentarios/>
    Q2827002CINSS001,
}
```

This is my code that deserializes the xml to the "Attributes" object:

```
    public static T Deserializar<T>(string respuesta, string nameSpace, string xpath = "//soap:Envelope/soap:Body/p:Respuesta")
    {


        T objetoDeserializado = default(T);
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.LoadXml(respuesta);

        Dictionary<string, string> nsAdicionales = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        nsAdicionales.Add("s", "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope");
        nsAdicionales.Add("soap", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
        nsAdicionales.Add("i", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
        nsAdicionales.Add("p", nameSpace);
        XmlNamespaceManager nsm = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
        foreach (string prefijo in nsAdicionales.Keys)
        {
            nsm.AddNamespace(prefijo, nsAdicionales[prefijo]);
        }
        XmlNode nodoObjeto = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode(xpath, nsm);
        if (nodoObjeto != null)
        {

            try
            {
                //Se añade el atributo XmlRootAttribute para aquellos casos que esté definido el objeto
                //con un nombre y se utilice con otro.
                XmlRootAttribute xRoot = new XmlRootAttribute();
                xRoot.ElementName = nodoObjeto.Name;
                xRoot.Namespace = nodoObjeto.NamespaceURI;
                var serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(T), xRoot);
                XmlReader xmlReader = nodoObjeto.CreateNavigator().ReadSubtree();
                var obj = serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
                objetoDeserializado = ((T)obj);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                respuesta = "Error al intentar deserializar el objeto soap: " + ex.Message;
            }
        }

        return objetoDeserializado;
    }
```

Where T is of the type "SCSP.ServiciosCompartidos.INSS.ConsultaPrestaciones.Atributes" well, it does not give an error, but if we see the Deserialized object, it puts all values as NULL

Please help.

Comment: Why manual parsing? From where are you got your classes? I suppose you have a soap-service that provides a scheme by which you generate C# files. Were probably generated client classes to access the service. Just use it.

Comment: Im using client classes generated by the service, but I need deserialize programming

Comment: Can you share the link to the svc service if it doesn't require authentication?

Comment: Thanks to everyone for your help, I have been able to see that if I put this line of code in the chunk where I deserialize:
"xRoot.IsNullable = true;", the xml deserializes correctly when the EstimatedTimeNode node comes with a value "0"
 "<TiempoEstimadoRespuesta> 0 <TiempoEstimadoRespuesta />" but when the node comes empty from the service:  "<TiempoEstimadoRespuesta\>"
 the result deserialize object is "null". ¿Somebody can help me?

Comment: I just solved the second problem, and it's removing the tags that come to me with no value in the xml like this: XmlNodeList emptyElements = xmlDoc.SelectNodes (@ "// * [not (node ())]"); For (int i = emptyElements.Count - 1; i> = 0; i--) {emptyElements [i] .ParentNode.RemoveChild (emptyElements [i]); } -

Comment: Hi @ararb78, I have seen that you are trying to communicate with intermediacion.redsara.es platform, how did you configure the security there. How did you sign the SOAP message with xmldsig?